# Characterization of $F$ being locally injective

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Let $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ be given by $F(x)=Ax+B(x,x)$ where $A:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ is a linear map and $B:\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ is a symmetric bilinear form. Show that $A$ is injective $\iff$ $F$ is injective near the origin.

$(\Longrightarrow)F$ isn't linear, so we can't use the characterization injective $\iff$ nullspace$=\{0\}$. Assume $A$ is injective and $F(x)=F(y)$. Then $A(x-y)=B(y,y)-B(x,x)$. I suspect the strategy is to find a $\delta>0$ such that $|x|,|y|<\delta\implies B(y,y)-B(x,x)=0$, but I'm not sure how to do this.

I'm also struggling the the converse $(\Longleftarrow)$

Does anyone have any ideas?